# In Mat.11:12 "...the kindom of heaven suffereth violence..." what does "suffereth" mean?

Tags: matthew, kjv

In **Mat.11:12**

> ... the kingdom of heaven suffereth violence ... **(KJV)**

What was meant by *suffereth* in current day use? Please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  Could you elaborate on your thoughts? What do you think it means? What about it specifically puzzles you or made you want to ask this question? Try to be as specific as possible in your questions -- this will help others know how best to answer them!

Comment: Good question. (+1). It highlights an interesting feature of the wording in the Greek.

Answer (score 5):

The Greek verb βίαζομαι, *biatsomai*, is one of a group of verbs which are classed as 'deponent'. There are arguments about how they should be viewed but, put in the simplest terms, they can be viewed as passive verbs.

So the activity is violence or force ([**see Strong 971**](https://biblehub.com/greek/971.htm)) but the activity is against the subject or agent of the sentence. The subject is passive and receives the activity of the verb.

The word 'suffer' is not really there :

> απο δε των ημερων ιωαννου του βαπτιστου εως αρτι η βασιλεια των ουρανων βιαζεται και βιασται αρπαζουσιν αυτην [*Received Text - Stephens, Beza, Elzevir and Scrivener are identical.*]

The kingdom 'receives force' or 'is subjected to violence' is the meaning of the  words. The next statement enlarges on the situation and specifies where the force is coming from. 'The forceful take it' or 'the violent claim it' are literal translations.

---

**Young's Literal** has :

> ... the reign of the heavens doth suffer violence and violent men do take it by force.

The **EGNT literal** interlinear (Englishman's Greek New Testament, Bagster) has :

> ... the kingdom of the heavens is taken by violence and [the] violent seize it.

The most concise translation, in my own view, would be :

> The kingdom of the heavens is forced and the forceful claim it.

---

However, note further that 'deponent' verbs are what may be termed 'reflexive' or 'responsive' verbs which opens up another depth of meaning, here.

If the verb is a matter of 'response' then the kingdom invites that response. The force exerted is a 'response'. It is not non-consensual, if I may use the word in this context.

Thus the wording used by Jesus does not envisage the brutal overpowering of an unwilling entity. Rather, the kingdom is such, in its nature, that it invites a confident claiming of it.

Which, I believe, indicates the nature of the faith which obtains entrance to it.

A good question to ask as it makes one pause for thought and re-consider the true nature of the wording of the text.

---

> He that overcometh shall inherit all things; and I will be his God, and he shall be my son. But the fearful, and unbelieving [...] shall have their part in the lake which burneth with fire and brimstone: which is the second death. [*Revelation 21:8 KJV*]

Comment: Nigel J - Many thanks - a characteristically excellent and considered response +1.

Comment: @DrPeterMcGowan Glad to be of service.

Comment: @NigelJ,Excellent exegesis +1

Comment: Hmm... I hate to break up the Mutual Admiration Society meeting but his information is completely wrong. Please read my link to what a deponent verb really is.

Comment: Perhaps you should make a note that your view of the deponent is novel and not reflected in the lexicons which note that in actual usage βίαζομαι is passive in form but active in sense. Please see BDAG (cited in my answer). Also, if you are going to present idiosyncratic Greek rules it would be appropriate to identify them as such and present your credentials in the Greek language. From where I sit you are yet again darkening counsel with bad information.

Comment: It is your place to cite primary sources. It is required by the site. Putting a link to a comment on the English Language site does not qualify because it is NOT a primary source or even a terribly relevant one. But, people on this site vote in cliques rather than objectively so you'll do fine here. The moderators seem to be long gone.

Comment: Also, you misinterpreted the post on the English Language site. His explanation is that there simply isn't an active FORM for certain verbs so the middle/passive FORM is used when expressing the ACTIVE sense. Read it again. But simply put you are muckying up the waters. PLEASE QUIT STUBBORNLY posting your whims as if it weren't just some notion you picked up from nowhere. To prevent, do what the site requires and cite your sources. And quit down voting all my posts.

Comment: Nigel J is spot on. The nature of God's kingdom is such that it is open and responsive to spiritually aggressive faith. 1 Cor 13:4 is another rendition of the word 'suffereth'- charity suffereth long; meaning the nature of charity or love is patient.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have no formal education in Greek.

The single word βιάζομαι is rendered by the KJV as "suffereth violence". In secular usage as a deponent has the "positive" or "active" sense of "coming with violence". In other words, it refers to the kingdom acting violently rather than being acted passively upon. The NLT gets it right, I think:

> NLT Matthew 11:12 And from the time John the Baptist began preaching
>   until now, the Kingdom of Heaven has been forcefully advancing, and
>   violent people are attacking it.

The ISV also has it right, I believe:

> ISV Matthew 11:12 "From the days of John the Baptist until the
>   present, the kingdom from heaven has been forcefully advancing, and
>   violent people have been attacking it,

Here is some more information/background on deponent verbs, which are passive in form but active:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deponent_verb

However, nothing's obvious as the meaning is obscure (though not opaque) and it might be good to consider the full lexicon entry which I have provided below:

```
βιάζω (Hom.+) nearly always as a mid. dep. βιάζομαι; aor. mid. ἐβιασάμην, pass. 2 sg. ἐβιάσθης Sir 31:21. Apart fr. Dg. 7:4; 10:15 most of this entry concerns probabilities relating to β. in Mt 11:12 and par. Lk 16:16. The principal semantic problem is whether β. is used negatively (‘in malam partem’) or positively (‘in bonam partem’), a problem compounded by the question of the function of these vss. in their literary context. In Gk. lit. β. is most often used in the unfavorable sense of attack or forcible constraint (s. L-S-J-M).

① to inflict violence on, dominate, constrain w. acc. (Herodas 2, 71; Menand., Dyscolus 253 [opp. πείθειν use of persuasion]; 371; Appian, Bell. Civ. 5, 35 §139; PAmh 35, 17 [213 b.c.] βιασάμενος αὐτούς; PGiss 19, 13; LGötzeler, Quaestiones in Appiani et Polybii dicendi genus 1890, 63; Esth 7:8 [rape]; En 103:14; 104:3) mistreat the poor people β. τοὺς ὑποδεεστέρους Dg 10:5.—With β. taken as pass., Mt 11:12 ἡ βασιλεία τ. οὐρανῶν βιάζεται is frequently understood in the unfavorable sense the reign/kingdom of heaven is violently treated, is oppressed (so the pass. e.g. Thu. 1, 77, 4; POxy 294, 16 [22 a.d.]; Sir 31:21. On the topic of violence to the divine, cp. Paus. 2, 1, 5 τὰ θεῖα βιάσασθαι=(it is difficult for a mere human) to coerce things in the realm of the divine.—GSchrenk, TW I 608ff; NRSV ‘has suffered violence’; its mng., w. β. understood as mid.: ‘has been coming violently’, s. 2 end); var. ways by which the violence is suffered have been suggested—(a) through hindrances raised against it (βιάζομαι=be hindered, be obstructed: cp. the use of the mid. in this sense: Synes., Provid. 1, 1, 89c of the evil man’s power, which strives εἴ πῃ τὸν θεῖον νόμον βιάσαιτο=[to see] whether it could perhaps ‘hinder’ the divine law; Jos., Ant. 1, 261). For the pass. in this sense, s. the versions: It., Vulg., Syr. Sin. and Cur. S. also Dalman, Worte 113–16; MDibelius, Joh. d. T. 1911, 26ff: hostile spirits.—(b) through the efforts of unauthorized pers. to compel its coming (s. HScholander, ZNW 13, 1912, 172–75)—(c) through attempts to occupy (an area) by force (a territory, Appian, Bell. Civ. 3, 24 §91).

② to gain an objective by force, use force, intr. (X., Mem. 3, 9, 10; Diod S 4, 12, 5 οἱ βιαζόμενοι=the ones who use force, the intruders; Plut., Mor. 203c; Epict. 4, 8, 40; Lucian, Necyom. 20, Hermot. 22; SIG 1042, 8 [Dssm., NB 85f (BS 258)]; 888, 24; 1243, 4f; PTebt 6, 31; PFlor 382, 54; Dt 22:25, 28; Philo, Mos. 1, 215; Jos., Bell. 3, 493; 518) of compulsion οὐ βιαζόμενος without using force (opp. πείθειν) Dg 7:4.—Of forcing one’s way (Demosth. 55, 17; Appian, Hann. 24 §106) w. εἴς τι enter forcibly into someth. (Thu. 1, 63, 1; 7, 69, 4; Polyb. 1, 74, 5; Plut., Otho 1072 [12, 10]; Philo, Mos. 1, 108 of a gnat forcing its way into bodily orifices εἰς τἀντὸς βιάζεται; Jos., Bell. 3, 423) ἡ βασιλεία τοῦ θεοῦ εὐαγγελίζεται καὶ πᾶς εἰς αὐτὴν βιάζεται the reign of God is being proclaimed and everyone takes (or tries to take [cp. Polemo Soph. B 11 Reader, s. p. 266f]) it by force Lk 16:16 (hyperbolic usage; on the question whether this is a perspective attributed to Jesus or to his opposition concerning moral miscalculation, s. FDanker, JBL 77, ’58, 234–36).—Makes its way w. triumphant force is preferred for Mt 11:12 by FBaur; TZahn; AHarnack, SBBerlAk 1907, 947–57; WBrandt, ZNW 11, 1910, 247f; ROtto, Reich Gottes u. Menschensohn ’34, 84–88; cp. NRSV mg. ‘has been coming violently’.—EGraesser, D. Problem der Parusieverzögerung, ZNW Beih. 22, ’57, 180ff; OBetz, Jesu heiliger Krieg, NovT 2, ’57, 116–37.

③ go after someth. w. enthusiasm, seek fervently, try hard, the sense is sought w. burning zeal is preferred by HHoltzmann; FDibelius, StKr 86, 1913, 285–88; et al. for Mt 11:12. A variation of this interpretation is the sense try hard, but the support sought in Epict. 4, 7, 20f is questionable, for this latter pass. rather refers to attempts at forced entry when one is not welcome.

④ constrain (warmly) if βιάζεται Lk 16:16 is to be understood as a passive, as POxy 294, 16 (22 a.d.), or in the same sense as the mid. in Gen 33:11; Judg 13:15, the sense would be invite urgently of the ‘genteel constraint imposed on a reluctant guest’ (so vHoffmann et al.; s. FDibelius [s. 3 above]; cp. the sense of Lk 14:23 ἀνάγκασον εἰσελθεῖν ‘compel them to come in’).—On usage at Qumran s. BThiering, NovT 21, ’79, 293–97.—DELG s.v. βία. M-M. TW. Spicq. Sv.
```

---

The "violent" nature of John can be seen in his fiery preaching:

> NIV Matthew 3:
>
> 7But when he saw many of the Pharisees and Sadducees coming to where
>   he was baptizing, he said to them: “You brood of vipers! Who warned
>   you to flee from the coming wrath? 8Produce fruit in keeping with
>   repentance. 9And do not think you can say to yourselves, ‘We have
>   Abraham as our father.’ I tell you that out of these stones God can
>   raise up children for Abraham. 10The ax is already at the root of the
>   trees, and every tree that does not produce good fruit will be cut
>   down and thrown into the fire.

We see that he also expected Jesus to execute fiery judgment, which he did not:

> NIV Matthew 3:
>
> 11“I baptize you withb water for repentance. But after me comes one
>   who is more powerful than I, whose sandals I am not worthy to carry.
>   He will baptize you withc the Holy Spirit and fire. 12His winnowing
>   fork is in his hand, and he will clear his threshing floor, gathering
>   his wheat into the barn and burning up the chaff with unquenchable
>   fire.”

While John was correct about the judgment Jesus was to bring he was wrong about the timing. In God's great wisdom the messiah is to have two comings:

- the first coming was for the purpose of being *rejected* and opening up the way for the gentiles through his death for sin and through his resurrection for justification:

> NIV Romans 11:
>
> 25 I do not want you to be ignorant of this mystery, brothers and
>   sisters, so that you may not be conceited: Israel has experienced a
>   hardening in part until the full number of the Gentiles has come in,

It is when he returned in 70AD that he brought the fiery judgment on the Jews:

> NIV Matthew 24:
>
> 1Jesus left the temple and was walking away when his disciples came up
>   to him to call his attention to its buildings. 2“Do you see all these
>   things?” he asked. “Truly I tell you, not one stone here will be left
>   on another; every one will be thrown down.”
>
> 3As Jesus was sitting on the Mount of Olives, the disciples came to
>   him privately. “Tell us,” they said, “when will this happen, and what
>   will be the sign of your coming and of the end of the age?”

But during his earthly ministry Jesus performed no judgment or wrath:

> NIV Luke 4:
>
> 16He went to Nazareth, where he had been brought up, and on the
>   Sabbath day he went into the synagogue, as was his custom. He stood up
>   to read, 17and the scroll of the prophet Isaiah was handed to him.
>   Unrolling it, he found the place where it is written:
>
> 18“The Spirit of the Lord is on me,
>
> because he has anointed me
>
> to proclaim good news to the poor.
>
> He has sent me to proclaim freedom for the prisoners
>
> and recovery of sight for the blind,
>
> to set the oppressed free,
>
> 19to proclaim the year of the Lord’s favor.”f
>
> 20Then he rolled up the scroll, gave it back to the attendant and sat
>   down. The eyes of everyone in the synagogue were fastened on him. 21He
>   began by saying to them, “Today this scripture is fulfilled in your
>   hearing.”

So Jesus words about the difference between John and himself is described in the nature of their message. John was rejected because he was too droll and Jesus because he was too nice.

Answer (score 0):

Definition of βιάζω (Strong’s 971, [billmounce.com](https://www.billmounce.com/greek-dictionary/biazo)):

> also written as a middle deponent, βιάζομαι, to urge, constrain,
> overpower by force; to press earnestly forward, to rush, Lk. 16:16;
> pass. to be an object of a forceful movement, Mt. 11:12

From the definition above, βιάζω is one of those verbs that can appear in either the active or middle voice. According to Ian Scott ([2018](https://ianwscott.blog/2018/02/28/making-sense-of-the-middle-voice-in-greek/)), “With these “middle-sometimes” verbs, you can also have the passive voice used.”

Looking at the Greek [Interlinear of Mt 11:12](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/matthew/11-12.htm), the voice of βιάζεται is noted as being either middle or passive (their forms are the same in the present tense). But according to the Greek concordance from billmounce.com, the word βιάζεται in Mt 11:12 is passive:

> From the days of John the Baptist until now the kingdom of heaven has
> suffered (biazetai | βιάζεται | pres pass ind 3 sg) violence, and the
> violent are taking it by force.

I think the second half of Mt 11:12 explains the first. That the agent of the action is stated to be not the kingdom of heaven but “the violent” (βιασταὶ, the noun form of the same verb βιάζεται) clears up much of the ambiguity regarding the passive voice of βιάζεται in Mt 11:12. The kingdom of heaven is the recipient of the forceful action – it suffers the violence rather than inflicts it.

Mt 11:12 can be understood on more than one level. The words describe the powerful effect of John’s preaching and the gospel on those who heard it, inspiring some to eagerly seize the kingdom of heaven for themselves, while inciting others to act violently against it. Though commentators generally disagree with the latter interpretation, was not John the Baptist in prison at the time that Jesus was speaking these words?